# How to run tensorflow-serving including its models by docker?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, debian, tensorflow-serving

The problem is, I want to run tensorflow-serving including its models by docker, but it seems that
the docker will make tensorflow-serving unable to load the folder.
In container itself, it can load models easily:

```
tensorflow_model_server --port=9000 --model_name=1 --model_base_path=/models/
```

But with docker, it cannot load models:

```
docker run --name tfx-test -p 8501:8501 -v "/models:/models" -e MODEL_NAME=5 -t tensorflow/serving
```

The result:

```
E tensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.cc:362] FileSystemStoragePathSource encountered a filesystem access error: Could not find base path /models/5 for servable 5
```

The models file:

```
|--models
    |-- 1
        |-- assets
        |-- saved_model.pb
        `-- variables
            |-- variables.data-00000-of-00002
            |-- variables.data-00001-of-00002
            `-- variables.index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `docker run` command to:

```
docker run -p 8501:8501 --mount type=bind,\
source=/models/1,\
target=/models/my_model/1 \
-e MODEL_NAME=my_model -t tensorflow/serving
```

And, you can see your model metadata at: `http://localhost:8501/v1/models/my_model/metadata` (Assuming you are running your docker from `localhost`)